# **FAILED (remote: 12 signature verify fail)** HTC One M7

Tags: rom-flashing, bootloader-lock, stock-rom, htc-one

```
C:\xxx>fastboot flash recovery c:\recovery.img
sending 'recovery' (10336 KB)...
OKAY [  1.988s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) signature checking...
**FAILED (remote: 12 signature verify fail)**
finished. total time: 2.966s
```

- HTC One M7 on the way back to stock
- Bootloader is locked 1.54.0000
- OS is 2.24.401.1

the message Output above is sample for everything I try to flash. Recovery ist stock. Message appears also when trying to install 2.24.401.1 via RUU.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Yepp, maybe. What is it you're trying to flash? My guess is, it's nothing provided by HTC, but some 3rd-party images. They are naturally *not* signed with HTC's signature, so the (locked) loader refuses to accept them as legit sources.

Comment: You'll need to flash a custom kernel to be able to do this.